# How to calculate the sum indicating the presence of particular value in each column and take total count for each id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**I have the following data frame:**

```
emp_id  male    female  Unknown  Month_Year
423       0       0        1     March-2016
423       1       0        0     April-2016 
423       0       1        0     May-2016
423       0       1        0     June-2016

789       1       0        0     June-2017
789       1       0        0     July-2017
789       1       0        0     August-2017
789       0       0        1     September-2017

856       1       0        0     March-2018
856       1       0        0     April-2018

987       0       1        0     June-2019
987       0       1        0     July-2019
987       0       1        0     August-2019
```

Please note in the columns male, female, and unknown the values indicate as mentioned below:

```
1 - "Yes"

0 - "No"
```

As can be seen, the gender is changing over a particular period for each emp_id. (But the emp_id remains the same, though the gender is changed).

So I have to take a count for each emp_id, whether the gender was changed over a particular period. I need something like this,

**Expected data frame:**

[image]

If observed in the columns male, female, and unknown:

For `emp_id 423` - There is a presence of gender in all the three columns, so the count is `3`.

For `emp_id 789` - There is a presence of gender in two columns, so the count is `2`.

For `emp_id 856` and `987` - There is a presence of gender only in one column, so the count is `1`.

I used the below code:

```
df['Total_count'] = df.groupby('emp_id')['male','female', 'Unknown'].agg(['sum']).reset_index()
```

But I got an error and also didn't meet the requirement.

So please let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df['Total_count'] = df.groupby('emp_id')[['male','female','Unknown']].transform('max').sum(axis=1)
```

What it is doing is grouping by the `emp_id` and finding the max for each column and then summing up those columns. It uses `transform()` so that the data size doesn't get reduced.

Comment: That's great! But I had one doubt is there any way that I can filter for only these columns(male, female, and unknown). Because I have other columns in the original data frame, so it is taking a count of another column values too.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I was looking for.